# Hide div with multiple buttons

Tags: jquery

i have this menu in my website

[image]

now i when you click on about us or students or events there are new links appears(collapse), now what i want is when about us, students or events expands the socials media icons disappear with jQuery
i tried to add hidden class to the icons it worked, but when you expand another link it appear again

```
jQuery('#block-expandedmenu li:nth-child(2),#block-expandedmenu li:nth-child(5),#block-expandedmenu li:nth-child(14)').click(function(){
if ($social.css('display') == "block")
{
  $social.hide();
}
else
{
  $social.show();
}});
```

please help if you can!
Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code you already tried?

Comment: i added the code i already tried

Answer (score 0):

Think about the workflow here:

You click on a link, social is displaying as a `block`, so it hides.

You click another link straight after, social does not satisfy that `if` condition any more since it is not displaying as a block, so it shows.

This is fully expected behaviour.

I think your 'issue' lies with your `if` condition.

My suggested approach would be (also in aid of simplifying your selectors), to add a class to the `li`s that you'd like to hide your social links upon clicking. So, if you have a class `hide-social`, you can refactor your code as follows:

```
jQuery('#block-expandedmenu li').click(function(){ // Trigger on all li elements
     $social.toggle(!$(this).hasClass('social-hide')); // Toggle visibility based on class
});
```